# Git Extensions 'Do not commit' not working

Tags: git-commit, git-extensions, git

I’m using the Git Extensions version [2.50.02 - latest (current)]. When I open the "Merge branches" I see the checkbox “Do not commit” is checked.

[image]

When I perform a Merge, I see all changes are committed (not pushed to the remote). I was expecting these changes are not to be committed so I could review before pushing to the remote branch.

Log shows Git Extension performs the following command

> git merge *branch* --no-commit --no-ff

Has anyone seen this issue? If yes is there a work around?

Comment: Have you checked if the changes are committed or just staged? Can you see a new merge commit in `git log`?

Comment: No I don't see a merge commit in git log. I think I sort of a understand what's happening. But not quite clear to the user. --no-commit means not to create a merge commit?

Comment: @ `--no-commit` just brings the changes but does not commit them. You need to run `git commit` after the no-commit merge. `--no-commit` allows you to make extra changes before a real commit is made.

Comment: "--no-commit just brings the changes but does not commit them" I was thinking the same. But that's the not the case. It does commi to the current branch. The difference is that it hasn't done a "merge commit".

Comment: @Spock: what evidence do you see, which leads you to think that the changes were committed ?

Comment: @LeGEC When I open the merged project in Visual Studio. I see the changes are committed. For example, don't have the red tick/green plus next to the file. But I can clearly see the changes are there and committed.

Comment: @Spock In Git, if a file has been changed, you still can't say for sure that it's committed. `git status` tells you if it's just modified or staged. The term "commit" may be different from what you have learned from other VCS.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks. When I do git status, it says my merged branch is ahead of x number of commits.

Comment: @Spock I think you can see "Changes to be committed: bla bla" in addition. If yes, these are the "staged" files with new changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on the `--no-commit` option states :

> --commit, --no-commit
>      Perform the merge and commit the result. This option can be used to override --no-commit.
>
> With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and do not autocommit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing.

What it does not state explicitly is : the modified files are staged (as if all files had been `git add`ed).
You can however see this pretty quickly if you run a `git status` on your repo.

If you want to review the differences before really committing, you will have to use the `--cached` opiton on `git diff` like commands :

```
git diff --cached
git difftool --cached
git difftool -d --cached
gitk --cached
# etc ...
```

---

If changes are already committed on your local machine, it is not what I would have expected from a plugin which states it has run `git merge branch --no-commit --no-ff`.

I would suggest to look in the log file at the actions after this line to see if by any chance a commit was triggered,
if you see no extra action there, and you do not remember to have done something which may have triggered the commit, it could be a bug in the extension.

Anyway, your changes are not published yet (not pushed), and you can still review the differences by running :

```
git diff HEAD HEAD~1
```

If you want to get rid of that commit, but keep the modifications as staged, you can also run :

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

As stated above, you can then review the differences using :

```
git diff --cached
```